# Grok filter for selecting and formatting certain logs lines

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am writing up a grok filter for parsing my application log which is unstructured. What i need is to look for certain lines and generate output in a specific format. e.g below are my logs

```
2018-05-07 01:19:40 M :Memory (xivr = 513.2 Mb, system = 3502.0 Mb, physical = 5386.7 Mb), CpuLoad (sys = 0%, xivr = 0%)
2018-05-07 01:29:40 M :Memory (xivr = 513.2 Mb, system = 3495.3 Mb, physical = 5370.1 Mb), CpuLoad (sys = 0%, xivr = 0%)
2018-05-07 05:51:19 1 :Hangup call
***2018-05-07 05:51:22 24 :Answer call from 71840746 for 91783028 [C:\xivr\es\IVR-Dialin.dtx***]
2018-05-07 05:51:30 24 :Hangup call
***2018-05-07 05:51:34 24 :Answer call from 71840746 for 91783028 [C:\xivr\es\IVR-Dialin.dtx]***
2018-05-07 00:31:21 45 :Device Dialogic Digital dxxxB12C1 [gc60.dev - Dialogic (SDK 6.0) ver 3.0.702:11646] (ThreadID: 1FF0, DriverChannel: 44)
2018-05-07 00:31:22 40 :Device Dialogic Digital dxxxB10C4 [gc60.dev - Dialogic (SDK 6.0) ver 3.0.702:11646] (ThreadID: 1B2C, DriverChannel: 39)
```

I need to enter only lines highlighted with *** in below format in my Kibana: Other lines should be simply ignored

> Logtimestamp:  2018-05-07 05:51:22
>   Channel_id:  24
>   Source_number:
>   71840746
>   Destination_Number: 91783028

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly write whatever is unique about that particular pattern, and use [pre-defined grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) for the rest.

In your case, the grok pattern would be,

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Logtimestamp} %{NUMBER:Channel_id} :Answer call from %{NUMBER:Source_number} for %{NUMBER:Destination_Number} %{GREEDYDATA:etc}
```

It will only match following pattern,

```
2018-05-07 05:51:34 24 :Answer call from 71840746 for 91783028 [C:\xivr\es\IVR-Dialin.dtx]
```

### **Explanation**

The [syntax for a grok pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) is `%{SYNTAX:SEMANTIC}`.

In your filter,

- `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Logtimestamp}` matches `2018-05-07 05:51:34`
- `%{NUMBER:Channel_id}` match `24`
- `:Answer call from` matches the string literally
- `%{NUMBER:Source_number}` matches `71840746`
- `%{NUMBER:Destination_Number}` matches `91783028`
- `%{GREEDYDATA:etc}` matches rest of the data i.e. `[C:\xivr\es\IVR-Dialin.dtx]`

in that order.

**Output:**

```
{
  "Logtimestamp": [
    [
      "2018-05-07 05:51:22"
    ]
  ],
  "Channel_id": [
    [
      "24"
    ]
  ],
  "Source_number": [
    [
      "71840746"
    ]
  ],
  "Destination_Number": [
    [
      "91783028"
    ]
  ],
  "etc": [
    [
      "[C:\\xivr\\es\\IVR-Dialin.dtx***]"
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can [test it here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, created it using the pattern and also added filter to drop the line with tag _grokpatternfailure. However i am running into a different issue now. File beat is showing below error. I have all the ports open between source and destination. IT seems the connection is getting closed.

Comment: 2018-05-15T07:55:57.521-0400 ERROR logstash/async.go:235 Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 10.5.52.168:54592->xx.xx.xx.xx:5044: wsasend: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
2018-05-15T07:55:58.522-0400 ERROR pipeline/output.go:92 Failed to publish events: write tcp 10.5.52.168:54592->xx.xx.xx.xx:5044: wsasend: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.